# Counting multiple value occurrences

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table like this in SQLLite database. `Name1` is the name of player 1 (same for `name2`) and `winner` represents which player won (Ex. first row, JOE won).

I would like to get all the names of opponents for a specific player, number of wins where the player won against that player and how many times have they played.

Ex. output for `JOE`:

```
name    wins    games
----------------------  
BILL    1       2     (JOE played againts BILL 2 times and JOE won 1)
NICK    2       2
GREG    1       3     (JOE played againts GREG 3 times and JOE won 1)
```

This is what I have so far, but it only outputs the name of all players:

```
SELECT name2 FROM games WHERE name1="JOE"
UNION
SELECT name11 FROM games WHERE name2="JOE"
```

Data in the table `games`:

```
id  name1       name2     winner  
----------------------------------------
1   JOE          BILL       1
2   BILL         JOE        1
3   NICK         JOE        2
4   JOE          NICK       1
5   NICK         BILL       1
6   GREG         JOE        1
7   GREG         JOE        2
8   GREG         JOE        1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach with aggregation and `case` statements.  Calculating the winner for each game is a bit tricky, because the winner refers to either the `name1` or `name2` column.  You seem to want the wins for the opponent, so this logic makes sure that the `winner` is not referring to `JOE`:

```
select (case when name1 = 'JOE' then name2 else name1 end) as name,
       sum(case when name1 = 'JOE' and winner = 2 then 1
                when name2 = 'JOE' and winner = 1 then 1
                else 0
           end) as wins,
       count(*) as games
from games g
where 'JOE' in (name1, name2)
group by (case when name1 = 'JOE' then name2 else name1 end);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I wanted the wins for "JOE", not for the opponent, but your code was easy to change.